# ASP.NET 5 beta7 CORS not working

Tags: asp.net, cors, asp.net-core

Using VS Code on OS X. I'm trying to get CORS working with 1.0.0-beta7. I'm not sure why it isn't working. By "isn't working" I mean I get a message in my javascript console that says: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load {ommitedurl}. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access." I have tried to use the AllowAllOrigins method and also specifying one or more urls with the WithOrigins method to no avail. I'm publishing to Azure as a web app if that matters. I've listed most of my code below. Can someone help me out?

Here is my dnvm list:

```
dnvm list

Active Version              Runtime Arch Location             Alias
------ -------              ------- ---- --------             -----
       1.0.0-beta7          coreclr x64  ~/.dnx/runtimes      
       1.0.0-beta5          mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes      
  *    1.0.0-beta7          mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes      default
       1.0.0-beta8          mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes      
       1.0.0-rc1-15798      mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes      
       dnx-mono             mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes      
       dnx-mono.1.0.0-beta8 mono         ~/.dnx/runtimes
```

Here are my project.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Cors": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-beta-23225",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "7.0.1"
}
```

Here is my Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.ConfigureCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowPlnkr",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://run.plnkr.co");
                });
        });
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowPlnkr"));
        });
        services.AddScoped<ITrackerRepository, TrackerRepository>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseCors("AllowPlnkr");
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
}
```

I also have EnableCors attribute on my Controller

```
[EnableCors("AllowPlnkr")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TrackerController : Controller
```

Comment: Try moving app.UseCors("AllowPlnkr"); before app.UseMvc();

Comment: Describe "not working"

Comment: @mason I have edited my question. Thanks

Comment: @Tratcher, No go. Tried moving app.UseCors("AllowPlnkr"); before app.UseMvc(); and it did not change the outcome.

Comment: @Richard.Davenport: Remove `UseCors` entirely and try as MVC can handle without it.

Comment: @KiranChalla I was just reading on github about that. I now only have app.UseMvc, app.UseDefaultFiles, and app.UseStaticFiles. I am still getting a "not allowed" message in my browser console.

Comment: @Richard.Davenport: hmm, also remove the line where you add the cors filter factory...a working cors sample https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/test/WebSites/CorsWebSite/Startup.cs#L15

Comment: @Richard.Davenport can you instead of updating your question to be "correct" can you roll back the question to being unsolved, and instead write is as an answer?

Comment: Thanks @vcsjones, I did that.

Answer (score 3):

The code was very close to working. I only needed to change my Startup.cs slightly. My root issue was that my client code was wrong. I tried using jQuery.ajax() and it worked. Thanks to everyone who commented and helped me.

Here is my Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.ConfigureCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowPlnkr",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://run.plnkr.co");
                });
        });
        services.AddScoped<ITrackerRepository, TrackerRepository>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
}
```